# ubuntu--vg-root partition will not free up space after deleting files

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, lvm

I moved a lot of files from an external drive to my home folder and my drive got full. Then I deleted some files and no space is freed. This is when I run `df -h`:

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         5,6G     0  5,6G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        1,2G  9,5M  1,2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  458G  440G     0 100% /
tmpfs                        5,6G  204K  5,6G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                        5,6G     0  5,6G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                    472M  117M  351M  25% /boot
cgmfs                        100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs                        1,2G   12K  1,2G   1% /run/user/108
tmpfs                        1,2G     0  1,2G   0% /run/user/1000
/home/akseli/.Private        458G  440G     0 100% /home/akseli
```

The files I've removed aren't open in any processes which i've checked with lsof. I've also rebooted the whole machine with no difference. I am not able to log in with graphical interface. I can only access text mode command line. I found that someone solved similar problem with running `tune2fs -m1 /dev/sda1` to free some space but it doesn't make any difference to me. I don't know if this is important but I'm using an encrypted home folder. Whenever I try to create a file I get an error saying no space left on device. Even when I've just deleted a large file.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid error :D

I was able to solve this by running:

```
tune2fs -m1 /dev/ubuntu--vg-root
```

Of course, `/dev/sda1` wasn't the drive that was full. After running that I was able to log the GUI. Also, after I removed a lot more files I was able to run:

```
tune2fs -m5 /dev/ubuntu--vg-root
```

in order to set it back again without my system getting full.